# Function invocation failed due to no matching argument type. web3.py, Python

Tags: python, web3py

I'm trying to swap tokens using `swapExactTokensForTokens()` (`Pancakeswap` Router function).

Here is my code

```
def swapTokens():
    amountIn = (w3.toWei(0.00001, 'ether'))
    amount1 = contractR.functions.getAmountsOut(
        amountIn,
        [wbnb, tokenToBuy]
    ).call()
    amountOutMin = amount1[1] * 0.9
    minAmountPrint = w3.fromWei(amountOutMin, 'ether')
    print('Minimum recieved:', minAmountPrint)

    swap_TX = contractR.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        [wbnb, tokenToBuy],
        myAccount,
        (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': myAccount,
        'value': w3.toWei(0.0001, 'ether'),
        'gas': 250000,
        'gasPrice': w3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
    signed_TX = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_TX, private_key=privateKey)
    tx_token = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_TX.rawTransaction)
    print(w3.toHex(tx_token))
```

But i keep getting error as the result:

```
Could not identify the intended function with name `swapExactTokensForTokens`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)` and keyword 
argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `swapExactTokensForTokens`: ['swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

I checked type of every argument passed to the function and thy matched.

Comment: the second argument u passed is type 'float' instead of 'int'. could that be the problem?

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks! Btw transaction failed. By any chance do you know a service that cna help me to figure out at what step of the tx it failed?

Comment: hey @richie, since that was it, maybe consider posting your somment as an answer so the OP can accept it for that sweet +10 reputation :b

Comment: i do like my rep ty @jemand771 :D

Comment: can u edit the question with the other problems details or open a new post with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second argument u passed is type 'float' instead of the required 'int'.

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved a similar problem, and it took me more than 3 hours to figure out that: **if your address has one space at the beginning or the end, then it is not an address and you will get the error `No matching argument type`**. But the point is, I've never thought that a space can take me 3 hours. So, check your address if there is any space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no double quotes `"` in addresses.

```
[wbnb.strip('"'), tokenToBuy.strip('"')]
```